# how do I detect OS X in my .vimrc file, so certain configurations will only apply to OS X?

Tags: macos, vim

I use my .vimrc file on my laptop (OS X) and several servers (Solaris & Linux), and could hypothetically someday use it on a Windows box.  I know how to detect unix generally, and windows, but how do I detect OS X?    (And for that matter, is there a way to distinguish between Linux and Solaris, etc.  And is there a list somewhere of all the strings that 'has' can take?  My [Google-fu](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=tsl&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aunofficial&q=.vimrc+has+unix+win32+gui_running+vms&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) turned up nothing.)

For instance, I'd use something like this:

```
if has("mac")
  " open a file in TextMate from vi: "
  nmap mate :w<CR>:!mate %<CR>
elseif has("unix")
  " do stuff under linux and "
elseif has("win32")
  " do stuff under windows "
endif
```

But clearly "mac" is not the right string, nor are any of the others I tried.

---

UPDATE:
The answer below ("macunix") seems fairly clearly like it *should* work, but for some reason it doesn't.  (Perhaps Apple didn't compile vim properly to respond to this? Seems unlikely.)

At any rate I guess I need to shift the focus of the question: does anyone have a solution that will achieve the same ends?  (That is, successfully detecting that the .vimrc file is being used on Mac OS X.)

Comment: `has("macunix")` works fine with the version of VIM installed by Homebrew, currently 7.4.1-936. YMMV.

Answer (score 52):

My updated `.vimrc` now uses the following:

```
if has("gui_running")
  " Gvim
  if has("gui_gtk2") || has("gui_gtk3")
    " Linux GUI
  elseif has("gui_win32")
    " Win32/64 GVim
  elseif has("gui_macvim")
    " MacVim
  else
    echo "Unknown GUI system!!!!"
  endif
else
  " Terminal vim
endif
```

My original answer is below

---

You could try what I do in my .vimrc:

```
if has("unix")
  let s:uname = system("uname -s")
  if s:uname == "Darwin"
    " Do Mac stuff here
  endif
endif
```

Although, to be completely transparent, my actual .vimrc reads:

```
let s:uname = system("echo -n \"$(uname)\"")
if !v:shell_error && s:uname == "Linux"
```

Mainly for detecting Linux (as opposed to OSX)

I'm not sure if you absolutely have to do that `echo -n \"$(uname)\"` stuff, but it had to do with the newline at the end of the `uname` call. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Maybe other people aren't running in to this problem but I had to change the above line to `if s:uname == "Darwin\n"`

Comment: @JasonAxelson You can remove the `\n` using substitution: `let s:uname = substitute(system("uname"), '\n', '', '')`

Comment: @rossipedia As it seems you wanted to be portable by testing `has("unix")`, you should use `uname -s` instead of `uname`.

Comment: @abeaumet correct, that would be the most portable way of doing it

Comment: Could instead do a regexp match with `if (system('uname') =~ "darwin")`. In `vim`, see `':h =~'` for other options, e.g. specificying case-sensitivity

Comment: No need for additional quotes - ```let s:uname = system("echo -n $(uname -s)")```

Answer (score 25):

I could not edit previous answer by adding two character only:

Here is correct one(passed on my macos 10.6 and default vim console version)

```
if has("unix")
  let s:uname = system("uname")
  if s:uname == "Darwin\n"
    " Do Mac stuff here
  endif
endif
```

system("uname") will come up with a return character, which makes second if condition failed. Just a small fix to add "\n".

Answer (score 15):

homebrew `vim` and `MacVim` returns true for `has('mac')`,
however so does `has('unix')`.  so to have it work across all unix platforms, a possible solution is:

```
if has('unix')
  if has('mac')       " osx
    set guifont=...
  else                " linux, bsd, etc
    set guifont=...
  endif
elseif has('win32') || has('win64')
  set guifont=...
endif
```

on the other hand, as of el capitan, the system `vim` returns false for `has('mac')`, and `uname` snooping is probably the way to go. it's an ancient version, never used it.

EDIT: recent macos has vim 9.x with `has(mac)` returning true.

Comment: I have tested, and this is the best solution. I guess it has so few upvotes because it's years newer, but it's a far simpler and equally effective solution.

Comment: Works on Mac with Vim 8 from Brew.

Answer (score 14):

I'm doing the same thing you are.  Don't try to detect the OS.  Instead, try to detect the type of vi/vim.

Check `:h feature-list` for a full list of the conditionals you can use.

Here's what I use to detect MacVim in my vimrc:

```
if has("gui_macvim")
  set guifont=Monaco:h13
endif
```

With this, you can detect for gvim, vi, vim, and whatever other flavors you might use.  The nice thing is that you could have vim-compatible settings on OS X.

[Reference from Vim Mailing list](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Simple-Environment-Questions-td1219801.html)

**EDIT:** This approach and its variants (`has('mac')`, `has('macunix')`, `has('gui_mac')`)do not work for vim in OS X.  If you use only use MacVim, you're safe.  If you're weird like me and like to occasionally jump into vim, one of the other solutions may be more suitable.

Comment: okay, this looks very useful, but whether I have TextMate available depends entirely on the OS, and not on whether it is a GUI version or a normal version of vim.  So for my purposes I'm not sure this will help me much.  I have a command to open a file in TextMate, which only applies if I'm on OS X, and I may add similar commands to open the current file in Sublime Text if I'm on Windows or Linux.  And I really almost never use GUI version of vim, just plain vim in the terminal.  (I find MacVim disorienting: it doesn't behave like a real Cocoa app, and it isn't a terminal app either.)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that TextMate could use vimrc files

Comment: TextMate doesn't use .vimrc files, but I put a command in my .vimrc file to open the current file in TextMate.  If I'm on OS X I can just type :mate and get the same file in TextMate, and use some of its very handy features, like bundles, etc.

Comment: @iconoclast bundles? Say no more! https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim + https://github.com/scrooloose/snipmate-snippets

Answer (score 9):

You want `macunix`. To quote `:h feature-list`:

```
mac     Macintosh version of Vim.
macunix Macintosh version of Vim, using Unix files (OS-X).
```

mac, AFAIK, only applies to old-school Macs, where \r is the line separator.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it should work, but for some reason it's not.  If I put my 'mate' command outside the if-block, it works.  But if I put it after 'if has("macunix")' then it fails.  Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that `mac` refers to old-school Mac OS (before OS X which is Unix-based).

Comment: Now vim has the 'osx' featuer. See: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/2cab0e191055a8145ccd46cd52869fbb9798b971/src/evalfunc.c#L5456

Comment: @Charles `osx` is nice indeed, however `nvim` doesn't have it at the time of writing.

Answer (score 6):

This is the easiest way I have found.

```
if system('uname -s') == "Darwin\n"
  "OSX
  set clipboard=unnamed 
else
  "Linux
  set clipboard=unnamedplus
endif
```

Answer (score -2):

gui_macvim gui_gtk2 gui_gtk gui_win32

There is a OS detection script somewhere on stackoverflow - more keywords to find it: win64 win95 macunix...