# Determine operating system in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I develop on Linux at home and on Windows at work. I'd like to use the same vimrc file in both environments. The problem I have with this is that on Windows, I want to have the editor use the Consolas font, and on linux, a different font. How can I check the environment so I can conditionally set the editor font? (I am familiar with the actual command to change font; it's the conditional I don't get)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I detect OS X in my .vimrc file, so certain configurations will only apply to OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842078/how-do-i-detect-os-x-in-my-vimrc-file-so-certain-configurations-will-only-apply)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Exception from my .vimrc

```
" adjust configuration for such hostile environment as Windows {{{
if has("win32") || has("win16")
  lang C
  set viminfo='20,\"512,nc:/tmp/_viminfo
  set iskeyword=48-57,65-90,97-122,_,161,163,166,172,177,179,182,188,191,198,202,209,211,230,234,241,243,143,156,159,165,175,185
else
  set shell=/bin/sh
endif
" }}}
```

Answer (score 20):

Have a look here:

http://objectmix.com/editors/149466-operating-system-checking-vimrc-files.html

(and I quote):

> ```
> let os = substitute(system('uname'), "\n", "", "")
> if os == "SunOS"
> " Do Sun-specific stuff.
> ...
> elseif os == "Linux"
> " Do Linux-specific stuff.
> ...
> endif
> ```

Comment: up vote because I only need this to work across unix systems.

Comment: Works well in combination with @AmokHuginnsson's answer.