# How to detect OS type and set ctags path in .vimrc?

Tags: vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I use vim on both FreeBSD and Linux os, sharing the same .vimrc configuration file. There's one problem that on FreeBSD the ctags binary path is /usr/local/bin/exctags, while on linux it's /usr/bin/ctags. So how to detect the OS type and set ctags binary path separately?

UPDATE:
I found once the taglist plugin is installed, it will automatically detect ctags path and store it in g:Tlist_Ctags_Cmd variable.

Comment: Check this if you haven't yet http://stackoverflow.com/a/6847015/151465

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue some time ago, and I solved it this way:

```
if executable('exctags')
   " On Free-BSD, exuberant ctags is installed as exctags
   let l:sCtagsName = 'exctags'
elseif executable('ctags')
   let l:sCtagsName = 'ctags'
endif
```

and then I use variable `l:sCtagsName` to call ctags. This works nice for me.

And, as long as you use ctags in Vim, why not to use the plugin [Indexer](http://goo.gl/N2N1c) which is made especially for that? It automatically generates tags for all files of project(s) and keeps tags up-to-date. You might want to check [my another answer](http://goo.gl/zJafm) to get more details.

Comment: Excellent! And thanks for recommending the indexer plugin for me.