# How to detect REAL Operating System in VimScript?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, msys2

I need to decide which binary executable file I need to choose, so I have to know the OS which Vim is running on.

I find there is related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846898/determine-operating-system-in-vimrc). But the `has('win32') || has('win64')` solution doesn't work for me, since when I'm using msys2 Vim on Windows, I will get `0` from the `has` solution, because the `has` solution only tells the OS which vim is compiled for, not the real OS which it is running on.

And when I need to decide which binary executable file I need to choose, I have to know the real OS. Is there any good idea about this problem?

Comment: Not an answer and I have no idea but what executable file do you want to run after you determine the real OS?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers such as LanguageClient-neovim, it decide which executable file to use by `has` now: https://github.com/autozimu/LanguageClient-neovim/blob/next/autoload/LanguageClient.vim#L311

Answer (score 2):

From [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/4df4cde3498fada91032858d7af213c2):

Define a global variable containing the current environment's name if it hasn't been already defined.

```
if !exists('g:env')
    if has('win64') || has('win32') || has('win16')
        let g:env = 'WINDOWS'
    else
        let g:env = toupper(substitute(system('uname'), '\n', '', ''))
    endif
endif
```

Use that global variable…

```
if g:env =~ 'DARWIN'
    " ... to do Mac OS X-specific stuff.
endif

if g:env =~ 'LINUX'
    " ... to do Linux-specific stuff.
endif

if g:env =~ 'WINDOWS'
    " ... to do Windows-specific stuff.
endif

if g:env =~ 'CYGWIN'
    " ... to do Cygwin-specific stuff.
endif

if g:env =~ 'MINGW'
    " ... to do MinGW-specific stuff (Git Bash, mainly).
endif
```

And so on.

Comment: OP mentions *the has('win32') || has('win64') solution doesn't work for me*?!

Comment: That's only the first half of the condition, whish is going to be false. The second half will work for his case.

Comment: thanks, I think this solution will works well when I define this variable and use it myself,  but what if I'm developing a plugin?  Following your idea, I think I have to define a global variable as a config option and tell my user to set it, and this seems not very smart since the OS is supposed to be auto detected...

Comment: And also, If I define it as a global variable in .vimrc,  them my .vimrc will not be portable between OS ...

Comment: And also, If I define it as a global variable in .vimrc,  them my .vimrc will not be portable between OS ...

Comment: If you are developing a plugin you can just create a global variable like `:let g:my_plugin_name_env = …` like all plugin authors do. Your plugin is responsible of setting that variable (with the code I provided) and there's no need whatsoever for user action. May I suggest posting another more specific question if that doesn't help? Your actual use case is not very clear.

Comment: In fact, in case of your plugin, the variable does not even need to be global, given that it doesn't depend on user input. I'd probably go with `s:uname`. :P