# How do I set up my .vimrc file to conditionally check for +ruby support?

Tags: ruby, vim

I recently added a script requiring vim-ruby,

The question I have is similar to: [how do I detect OS X in my .vimrc file, so certain configurations will only apply to OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842078/how-do-i-detect-os-x-in-my-vimrc-file-so-certain-configurations-will-only-appl)

but perhaps there is a clean way to check (as I want to propagate the same .vimrc file across all OSes: Win7-64, Linux(RHEL/Ubuntu), Mac, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `has('ruby')` in an `if` statement. Try `:echo has('ruby')` to see for yourself.

As an addendum, this works for all "+features" listed in `:version`.

Comment: Thanks for generalizing that- I'm new to building functional vimrc files, since the only thing I would put in there is 'set nowrap' for years.