# Find out vim executable name inside vimrc

Tags: vim

I share my `~/.vimrc` file between different computers and use it with three different vims (macvim in mac, gvim in my Ubuntu desktop and plain old vim in the servers which I manage)

Most of what I have in my `~/.vimrc` file applies to all three instance, but I want to make some small changes based on which vim I am using (like removing certain plugins when invoked vim from console)

My question is how do I distinguish different vim executables in my `~/.vimrc`, so that I can have different settings for different vim's?

Comment: There is already a similar question, hopefully it will help you
[Original Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842078/how-do-i-detect-os-x-in-my-vimrc-file-so-certain-configurations-will-only-appl

Comment: @societyCoding For links in comments, `[name](url)` is the format. Just thought you'd like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I, too, use the same config in different environments. This is what I have in my `vimrc`:

```
let os = substitute(system('uname'), '\n', '', '')

if has('gui_running')
  " generic GUI settings go here

  if os == 'Darwin' || os == 'Mac'
    " MacVim-specific settings go here

  elseif os == 'Linux'        
    " GVim-specific settings go here

  endif

else      
  " generic CLI Vim settings go here

  if os == 'Darwin' || os == 'Mac'        
    " Mac OS X-specific CLI Vim settings go here

  elseif os == 'Linux'
    " Linux-specific CLI Vim settings go here

  endif

endif
```