# Vim "yank" does not seem to work

Tags: vim, yank

I'm fairly new to Vim. Tonight, I learned about the "yank" command, but when I try to use it in MacVim, it doesn't do anything. Neither `Y` nor `y{motion}` do anything. I tried with a default `.vimrc` to rule out any weird config issues.

Google-fu is failing me. This feels like a noobie issue. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What does `Y` do? Did you mean `y`?

Comment: @icedwater: `Y` is a synonym for `yy`.

Comment: Ah, thanks @Amadan - I'd never use it since `yy` is much faster than going to the shift key for me. Good to know though.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question! It was driving me crazy too. I kept trying to paste from the system clipboard. ;-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`y`ank by itself merely copies the line into a clipboard - you will need to `p`aste it onto the next line or onto the `P`receding one to use the copied line. To cut the line as well, use `d`elete.

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot. I thought that "yank" actually removed the line AND copied it. Ugh, I can't believe I just wasted an hour on this. Thanks @icedwater!

Comment: No problem, you would be looking for `d`elete in that case.

Comment: @AdamRubin - And you can skip the yank if you want to **cut** & paste rather than **copy** & paste...

Answer (score 60):

If you have the setting `set clipboard=unnamedplus` in your `.vimrc` then this will not be working.

For OSX you have to use `set clipboard=unnamed`

For Linux you will probably need to use `set clipboard=unnamedplus`

Heres the snippet from my personal `.vimrc`

```
if system('uname -s') == "Darwin\n"
  set clipboard=unnamed "OSX
else
  set clipboard=unnamedplus "Linux
endif
```

Comment: Thanks, running OSX here, your tip solved the problem.

Comment: I want to share the same `.vimrc` across Mac and Linux - is it possible to add some `IF` inside config? ok I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842078/how-do-i-detect-os-x-in-my-vimrc-file-so-certain-configurations-will-only-appl

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich, yes thanks for asking. I have updated the answer with a snippet from my personal config.

Comment: +1 I am using i3 and Vim and have been looking for a solution for a couple of hours now, and this solved my problem. I was able to copy past from applications into Vim, and from Vim to other Vim instances and Terminals but not from Vim into for instance Chromium and other applications. Setting `clipboard=unnamedplus` solved this issue. Just got lucky stumbling upon this answer. Even though it's an relatively old answer: Thank you sir! Now I can finally continue doing everything with just the my keyboard and put aside the mouse :)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It solved my problem.  My `.vimrc` have `set clipboard=unnamedplus`.

Comment: I had a linux vimrc and I moved to a new OSX machine and ran into this!

Answer (score 5):

It does not do anything *visible* - just like Ctrl-C (Edit/Copy) in other editors. Try the command `p` (paste) after it - that's the equivalent of Ctrl-V - to put what was yanked into the document.

Answer (score 4):

The yank command pulls text into a clipboard.  For example `yy` simply yanks the current line into the common clipboard.  You can "paste" the contents of the clipboard with `p`.  You can also yank into *named buffers* using something like `"ayw` to yank the text from the current position to the end of the word into a buffer named `a`.  The correspond put is `"ap`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm *expecting* it to do, but when I try to use it, it doesn't do *anything*. I'm trying to use it in normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

If your using Ubuntu or Mint the only solution that seemed to work for me was to uninstall vim and install the package "vim-gnome" instead.  Then adding the line:

set clipboard=unnamedplus

to my .vimrc worked as expected.

Comment: `unnamedplus` only works on Linux. OSX uses `unnamed`